# Access Google spreadsheet API without auth token

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-authentication, google-developers-console

I have created Google Spreadsheet, and given edit access to all (can edit even without login).

Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DKp_nAw37yppmAcfmVI7h340mC2kkI89EOHPGdxu620/edit#gid=0). I would like to update this sheet with Google Spreadsheet API. But I am getting error. My requirement is update the sheet thru API even without access credential.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution ? It seems that even with "anyone can edit mode" we can only read data but not change or add some

Answer (score 19):

It is possible to write to spreadsheet without `OAuth` or `API Keys`. You need to use `Service Account Keys`.

Here is what I did for my Node.js environment.

1. Get a service account key from https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials (You can here also restrict what this keys is allowed todo)

   1. When creating, make sure you click the `Furnish a new private key`
   2. Select `JSON` when it asks you how to download the key.
2. The `service account key` you have just generated includes a `client_email`.

   1. Go to you google spreadsheet and allow this `client_email` to have write access on this document
3. Use the following code to authenticate

   `` let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(client_email, null, private_key, [
               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
           ]);
   //authenticate request
   jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
        // at this point the authentication is done you can now use `jwtClient` 
        // to read or write to the spreadsheet
   }); ``

`client_email` and `private_key` are part of the `service account key`

A more detailed description can be found here.  http://isd-soft.com/tech_blog/accessing-google-apis-using-service-account-node-js/ Also, all credit goes to this page.

Comment: NVM (for future viewers) just wasn't calling require("googleapis").google (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#getting-started)

Comment: How can we achieve this through Java?

Answer (score 4):

You need to be [authorized to make such requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing)

> Every request your application sends to the Google Sheets API needs to
>   identify your application to Google. There are two ways to identify
>   your application: using an OAuth 2.0 token (which also authorizes the
>   request) and/or using the application's API key. Here's how to
>   determine which of those options to use:
>
> If the request requires authorization (such as a request for an
>   individual's private data), then the application must provide an OAuth
>   2.0 token with the request. The application may also provide the API key, but it doesn't have to. If the request doesn't require
>   authorization (such as a request for public data), then the
>   application must provide either the API key or an OAuth 2.0 token, or
>   both—whatever option is most convenient for you.

That's it. There's no bypassing authorization.

Comment: I have created API Key, and added that in postman header
Key : Authorization
Value :key=<api_key>. But still its not working.

Comment: @Nageswaran You have to pass it in the query string, not header. See https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#APIKey

Comment: The same key is working for GET requests but not PUT requests :/. Am I missing something?

Comment: Same issue here. The restrictions above only cover reading data not writing to a sheet that has full edit access open to the public. Wish they would be clearer about this. There's good use cases to writing to a completely open form.

Answer (score 2):

Finally digged deep enough and found the answer. Any kind of writing, even to publicly editable sheets requires an OAuth flow:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36755576#comment3

Answer (score 1):

Jürgen Brandstetter's answer above is completely right. Using Postman, I have been successful without using an OAuth token (I needed my personal API key and a service account) - I have written to a new sheet (in fact I did a batchUpdate operation with two steps, first create a new sheet and then pasteData on it). I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57620483/5726057) to create a service account, downloaded the credentials JSON and used it to create and sign a JWT string that is later used as Bearer.

Here is the Java code to obtain the JWT string:

```
    private static String getSignedJWT() throws IOException {
        InputStream in = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/downloaded-service-account-creds.json");
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found");
        }
        ServiceAccountCredentials serviceAccountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(in);
        GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = serviceAccountCredentials
                .createScoped(Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS));

        PrivateKey privateKey = serviceAccountCredentials.getPrivateKey();
        String privateKeyId = serviceAccountCredentials.getPrivateKeyId();

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(null, (RSAPrivateKey)privateKey);
        String signedJwt = JWT.create()
                .withKeyId(privateKeyId)
                .withIssuer(serviceAccountCredentials.getClientEmail())
                .withSubject(serviceAccountCredentials.getClientEmail())
                .withAudience("https://sheets.googleapis.com/")
                .withIssuedAt(new Date(now))
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(now + 3600 * 1000L))
                .sign(algorithm);

        return signedJwt;
    }
```

Dependencies needed: com.auth0:java-jwt and com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http.

Here's the curl that uses the JWT string generated above:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/YOUR_SHEET_ID:batchUpdate?key=ANY_PERSONAL_API_KEY' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_JWT_STRING' \
--data-raw '{
    "requests": [
        {
            "addSheet": {
                "properties": {
                    "title": "newPred",
                    "sheetId": 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "pasteData": {
                "coordinate": {
                    "columnIndex": 0,
                    "rowIndex": 0,
                    "sheetId": 0
                },
                "delimiter": "\t",
                "data": "col1\tcol2\nPeter\t25",
                "type": "PASTE_NORMAL"
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what asked but here is a solution with google-api-nodejs-client worked for me:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const sheets = google.sheets('v4');
const spreadsheetId = '.........';

(async () => {

  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: './my_service_account_privatekey.json',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'],
  });

  // get
  try {
    const getResult = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      auth,
      spreadsheetId,
      range: 'Sheet1!B2:C4'
    })
    console.log('Got values:', getResult.data.values)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Get error:', error)
  }


})()
```

docs: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#using-the-keyfile-property