# API key not authenticating for google sheets API

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets-api

I am creating a website to manage requests for our schools Veteran's Day applications. My goal is to take data and pass it to google sheets. The HTML is currently experimental and is optimized for development. Everything is working fine until execute() in line 57 of index.html. I am getting a 401 error when attempting to send data, even though my API key is up to date. This is the first time I have tried to do this kind of thing, so keep that in mind and explaining things like you're talking to a five-year-old. [github repo](https://github.com/traczpasruchu/veterans-website)
Ignore everything but [index.html](https://github.com/traczpasruchu/veterans-website/blob/master/index.html) in the repo

Comment: API key does not allow writing data. Only OAuth2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I write to Google Sheet via Google Sheets API without Oauth, using developer key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580909/can-i-write-to-google-sheet-via-google-sheets-api-without-oauth-using-developer)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but is there a way to write to Google sheets without the user logging in, because there is a good chance that some of the people using this website won't have a Google account

Comment: @SawyerPutnam, try to use the google service account key. There is an already answered question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045183/access-google-spreadsheet-api-without-auth-token